# Is it possible for Cordova plugins to work with PWA?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I am looking for a PWA deployment, currently, I am using the Ionic app. I am using Cordova plugins which are only supported on the device. How do that work with Ionic on a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can, if you pack your web app as a cordova hosted web app. To put it in other words, build a regular cordova app with a webview pointing to your web server URL. Your web-app can have code interacting with cordova plugins.

There is no way to use Cordova plugins in a PWA app without packing it work cordova (at-least as of 2018 March and in near feature). Said that, you cant make use of cordova plugins in PWA apps when it is running in browser / installed it using "add to home screen option".

PWA apps as such are run in browsers (including installed ones using "Add to Home Screen option", but without address bar). Browsers don't have native code access, which are needed for Cordova plugins to work.

In a regular cordova app, including Ionic cordova, its a native app with webview. So the native part of the app has access to native API, which is wrapped with JS interfaces for use in web apps.

Comment: for iOS it's not giving me the 'Add to home' option.  Have you seen this issue before?
Also, if I'm unable to get that option to work on iOS, are there other plugins I could use in a PWA to use functionality like location services, push notification and google authentication?  Those are my most important cordova plugins I'm using.

Comment: PWA is still a regular web application. In that sense, you can wrap that with Cordova and use any of cordova plugin just like how you would use with other web applications. "Add to home screen" popup wont work in iOS. Thats not an issue. Thats a functionality Apple is still not providing.  But the user can add to home screen from the safari menu.

Comment: And reg push notifications, it has browser/platform limitations as well. iOS don't support it yet. https://caniuse.com/push-api